# PyCharm terminal does not use venv, but "Python Console" does

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, I have created a new Python project with its own `venv` environment.

But, for some reason, executing `pip install ...` in PyCharm's terminal uses the systemwide Python installation instead of the `venv`. Therefore, I cannot import the package from PyCharm's "Python Console", which does use the `venv` interpreter as expected.

Running `python` via the terminal starts the system interpreter as well. The command line prompt shows the `(venv)` prefix and I have deactivated my Anaconda environment via `conda deactivate`. I am running PyCharm on Windows. No error message is shown.

[image]

Anybody with the same experience?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the error is in the blacked-out path: One of the folders contains special characters in its name. And although spaces and hyphens are generally not a problem, it's a different story for non-ASCII characters like German umlauts. Apparently, PyCharm can handle them - but not `venv`.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm, vevn can`t find pip inside itself and use global one when there is russian letters in one folder. So make sure all path to venv contains only eng letters and/or with spaces

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).